# Suppress console logs from code being tested

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm unit testing a function which contains a `console.log()` call.

How can I prevent the output of that call from being displayed in the output console of my test runner, in this case, Karma.
I'm using Jasmine.

I'm looking for a more elegant way than overriding browser's `console` methods, preferably a config.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Set `client.captureConsole = false` in your `karma.conf.js` [config set function](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html).

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        client: {
            captureConsole: false
        }
    });
};
```

Original [feature request](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/744).

Comment: Who is awesome? Yes *you* are. Thank you.

Comment: This looks like it suppresses _all_ output logging, even a majority of what Karma logs. I don't see how this is an acceptable solution.

Comment: @claudekennilol (and others) see my answer for a configuration that suppresses the logging for the called methods only

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30052897/suppress-console-logs-from-code-being-tested/30564812#30564812) is that it also suppress Karma logs.

If you only want to suppress the logging for the called methods set `browserConsoleLogOptions.level` to an appropriate level in your `karma.conf.js`. Setting `browserConsoleLogOptions.level` to `"warn"` will suppress all the `log` and `debug` logs.

copy-paste-ready snippet:

```
// file: karma.conf.js

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        // other options...
        browserConsoleLogOptions: {level: "warn"}
    }
}
```

See the [karma configuration file documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/6.3/config/configuration-file.html) for references.

Comment: beware of:  level "log" always is logged. (Source: docs http://karma-runner.github.io/5.0/config/configuration-file.html)

Comment: @SebastianViereck actually this is working as expected. I have a large project with multiple `console.*` calls and (for example) if I set the level to `warn` in karma.conf.js the `log` calls are correctly suppressed: if you want I can provide a minimal complete working example to show this. I don't know what that sentence means, and I also find it ungrammatical.